# In Svelte, using Auth.js, how can I get a session in a +server component

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Using svelte kit ( https://kit.svelte.dev ) and Authjs ( authjs.dev ), how can you retrieve the user session in a +server.(ts/js) endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

The session can be found in the request event ( [RequestEvent](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-requestevent) ), under request.locals.getSession() function.

Example:

```
import type { RequestEvent } from './$types';
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
export const GET = async (request: RequestEvent) => {

    const sessions = await request.locals.getSession();
    const sessions_as_json_string = JSON.stringify(sessions, null, 4);
    return json({
        sessions_as_json_string 
    });
};
```

Comment: But how can you get the session id? This object only has name, email, image and expires